# What is wrong with my code (Cloud Kit)

Tags: xcode, swift

So this is my code to allow an alert and the text that is written inside the alert, gets saved in the cloud.  I am actually following a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQ3nLV2778U
Im getting 2 error messages tho on some of my code!

1. Error : Any object is not identical to CKRecords (located at self.post = post)
2. Error : CKRecords does not have a member named subscript (located at newPost ["content"]

I wrote the code the exact way the guy did in the tutorial except I have error messages and he doesn't! How do I fix these?

```
    var posts = [CKRecord]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

func loadData() {
    posts = [CKRecord]()

    let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Post", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))
    publicData.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (CKRecord, NSError) -> Void in
        if let posts = CKRecord{
            self.posts = posts //Error "Any Object is not Identical to CKRecords"
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }

    }
}

@IBAction func createPost(sender: AnyObject) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Post", message: "Enter New Post", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField:UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Your Post"
    }
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Post", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        let textField: AnyObject = alert.textFields!.first!

        if textField.textLabel??.text != "" {
            let newPost = CKRecord(recordType: "Post")
            newPost["content"] = textField.textLabel??.text //ERROR "CKRecord does not have a member named subscript"



            let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
            publicData.saveRecord(newPost, completionHandler: { (record: CKRecord?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    print("Post Saved")
                }
            })

        }






    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your Xcode to the latest version.

This syntax is available starting from a certain version of Swift. I do not recall which version exactly you need, but if you just update Xcode your issue will be gone.